# Adding mesh to enclosed semicircle MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am currently trying to produce a 2D heat transfer analysis on an alloy which has a shape of a semicircle, (and then introduce a heat source on this shape). I found myself unable to produce a mesh for that specific shape, the code below shows what I have done up until now, if anyone could possibly point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

initially I set up the grid parameters as follows:

```
%-------------------GRID SETTINGS----------------------%
Sx = 10;                    %physical width
Sy = 10;                    %physical height
Nx = 100;                   %number of points x-axis
Ny = round(Nx*Sy/Sx);       %number of points y-axis

Nt = 500; 

%-------------------GRID RESOLUTION---------------------%
dx = Sx/(Nx);
dy = Sy/(Ny);
```

and worked on creating the shape of an enclosed semicircle as below:

```
%---------------------SHAPE CREATION--------------------%      
r1 = 0.07;                          %radius 1, m
r2 = 5;                             %radius 2, m
phi = 0:0.01:pi;
x = r2*cos(phi); x = [x,x(1)];      %x coordinates 
y = r1*sin(phi); y = [y,y(1)];      %y coordinates

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use polar coordinates for your mesh and then visualize the results in cartesian coordinates. Check out the example below, hope this gives you a starting point (not really sure why you applied two different radius (`r1`, `r2`) to your `x`,`y` coordinates - so I assumed you have a minimal and maximal radius).

```
Nx = 100; 
r1 = 1;                          %radius 1, m
r2 = 5;                          %radius 2, m
phi = 0:0.01:pi;

% generate mesh grid in polar coordinates
radius = linspace(r1, r2, Nx/2);
[Radius, Phi] = meshgrid(radius, phi);

heat = Radius.^2; % some "fake" heat data

% plot results (in cartesian coordinates)
mesh(Radius.*cos(Phi), Radius.*sin(Phi), heat)

axis equal
% top view
view([-0.2 90.0])
```

[image: Resulting mesh]

Comment: Be aware that the points in the resulting grid are not uniformly spaced. They are more concentrated close to the inner semicircle than close to the outer one. The solver for the heat eq'n must take that into account.